# Nullable(of Guid) with Generic Delegate causes weird (hidden) error?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

*Scroll to the bottom, EDIT 19 onwards.  See @Chris's comments also for good examples*

VB:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private Delegate Sub AnEventHandler(Of T)(ByVal newValue As T)
    Private Event OnSomething As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid))
End Class
```

C#:

```
public class Class1
{
    private delegate void AnEventHandler<T>(T newValue);
    private event AnEventHandler<Nullable<Guid>> OnSomething;
}
```

With the above VB code in .Net3.5 and .Net 4, Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, regardless of project type, you get the following error:

Type 'Global.System.Guid' is not defined.

You cannot navigate to the error by double clicking, and no line/coloumn numbers are given.

Do *not* quote from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/afd0a8e9-31f2-424b-871a-b7d8ebdb290c/) that:
"T" can only be a Class, an interface or a type parameter.

...because that is *wrong*, as proven below.

To confirm this statement, a couple of facts

[Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) is a structure.  Yet, the following compiles:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private Delegate Sub AnEventHandler(Of T)(ByVal newValue As T)
    Private Event OnSomething As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Integer))
End Class
```

You can use Nullable Guids as shown here:

```
Private Sub StackOverflowTest()
    Dim s As Nullable(Of Guid)
    If s.HasValue Then
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

That code compiles and works as you might imagine.  Even the following code which uses generics and nullable guids works!!

```
Private Sub StackOverflowTest2(Of T)()
    ' do stuff
End Sub

Private Sub StackOverflowTest3()
    StackOverflowTest2(Of Nullable(Of Guid))()
End Sub
```

However, my particular example listed at the very top, does not work.  Why?  Clearly, T *does* work with structures...

EDIT 19ish! =D

1. Create a VB.Net Console Application
2. Add the following to "Module1.vb"

   Module Module1

   ```
   Sub Main()
       Dim testCase1 As Nullable(Of Integer)
       testCase1 = 2190
       StackOverflowTest1(Of Nullable(Of Integer))(testCase1)
       Dim testCase2 As Nullable(Of Guid)
       testCase2 = Guid.NewGuid
       StackOverflowTest1(Of Nullable(Of Guid))(testCase2)
       Dim testCase3 As Nullable(Of Guid)
       testCase3 = Nothing
       StackOverflowTest1(Of Nullable(Of Guid))(testCase3)
   End Sub

   Private Sub StackOverflowTest1(Of T)(ByVal param As T)
       Console.WriteLine(param.ToString)
   End Sub
   ```

   End Module

Results:

2190

5ef4ed7c-2720-4b37-b8ca-4ac044ec70d0

*<<< Nothing here to it just gave carriage return*

LAST EDIT (I hope):

It's all gone quiet since Edit 19ish and @Chris reinforcing the issue with a good example (thank you Chris).  I'll make the question a little easier (and attempt to tidy up all of the above), can anyone prove this is not an MS bug or similar?  It seems to be something under the hood is not correctly wired up for VB.Net with regards to Nullable Structures and Events?  However, all other cases using the Nullable Structures *does* appear to work?

Comment: It would appear to be your PC. 
In your project do you have a reference to System?
Which version of System are you referencing?

Comment: Look what I found: "in VB, "T" can only be a Class, an interface or a type parameter. Not a structure. A Nullable is a structure." Hope it helps.

Comment: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/afd0a8e9-31f2-424b-871a-b7d8ebdb290c/) There is some kind o solution also.

Comment: Smudge202 = Tommy Long.  That was my post, and I'm still lost as to why "'T' cannot be a structure" yet I can compile code against Nullables (structures) so long as the Nullable is not 'Of Structure'

Comment: This doesn't seem to be restricted to Guid, seems any struct has this problem, eg AnEventHandler(Of ConsoleKeyInfo?) or AnEventHandler(Of LockCookie?). I've tried several combinations, and it seems specific to Nullable.

Comment: @reniuz that post's answer seems slightly incorrect though, since VB does support the structure restriction on nullable types, and does support T as a value type.

Comment: +1 chris, as proven in my most recent edit (19ish) you *can work with nullable guids and generics*

Comment: Here's an example showing various combinations of value types, https://gist.github.com/1010004 it is only Nullable(Of T) when T is not an aliased type name that fails.

Comment: I'm not going crazzy, right!?  Everyone has been quoting that incorrect answer on the MSDN post, but actually, it seems there is something not wired up correctly? - Could hug you for looking at this through my eyes @Chris! =D

Comment: at the moment, since Nullable(Of Integer) works which is a structure, and no good reason why other structures should fail I'm leaning towards compiler bug.

Comment: More so since you can use Nullable(Of Structure) in many other situations, just not with the events it seems?

Comment: This is possible, since events are handled _very_ differently from function calls (i.e. events use message queues). The .NET framework just tries to hide this from you, but it all comes down to assembler and Windows :)

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674265/nullable-of-structures-do-not-work-with-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear to be a bug in the code generated behind the scenes by the VB.Net compiler. The following compiles fine, and should be functionally equivalent:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private Delegate Sub AnEventHandler(Of T)(ByVal newValue As T)
    Private OnSomethingEvent As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid))
    Private Custom Event OnSomething As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid))
        AddHandler(value As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid)))
            Me.OnSomethingEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Me.OnSomethingEvent, value), AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid)))
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(value As AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid)))
            Me.OnSomethingEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Remove(Me.OnSomethingEvent, value), AnEventHandler(Of Nullable(Of Guid)))
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(newValue As System.Guid?)
            Dim aeh = OnSomethingEvent
            If Not aeh Is Nothing Then
                aeh(newValue)
            End If
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
End Class
```

(Hence, also, why you don't get line numbers for the errors - the errors are appearing in code that isn't present in any line you've written)

Comment: That looks great @Damien.  So the bug is in the auto-generated code and not in some dark dusty cupboard of the .Net Framework core somewhere, writing the event explicitly does seem to negate the errors.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added your answer as the workaround for the [connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674265/nullable-of-structures-do-not-work-with-events#). I've named and thanked you on there so hopefully that's ok? Cheers.

Comment: @Smudge202 - no problem - it was a fun one to dig into.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in VB a type parameter can only be a class, not a structure.

A quick and dirty workaround would be to box the Guid? within an Object.

Comment: Thanks Paulo.  Last bit, why does Nullable Of Integer work but not the guid?  I appreciate there is a difference in Value type and structure, but Nullable is a structure, yet when combined with value type, it still works?

Comment: Not sure about this since I just noticed that when you pointed out, and if you add a "As Structure" constraint to the Delegate, you'll notice it errors out with "'System.Nullable' does not satisfy the 'Structure' constraint for type parameter 'T'. Only non-nullable 'Structure' types are allowed.".
All custom structures generate the same error as your question, it does work out with native value types, such as Integer like you pointed out (and Double, Char, etc.).

Comment: Interesting. So there seems to be some sort of special wiring for nullable in vb?  And my OP is probably more a case of why am I *not* getting error messages in these cases, as opposed to why am I getting messages...?

Comment: Give me 5 mins to see if I can get a test case to actually run code against Generics and Nullable Guids.  Although it compiles, it might not run through.  If it doesn't, I'll mark you as answer ;-)

Comment: I'm interested in how you got it to compile actually.

Comment: See my latest edit... that compiles, runs, and outputs the results you would expect.

Comment: @Paulo, you should remove the "Unfortunately in VB a type parameter can only be a class, not a structure."  That's definitely not correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this one down to a bug in the Framework.  I've posted a [bug report on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674265/nullable-of-structures-do-not-work-with-events#details).

I'll not mark my own answer as *the* answer for another day or two, in case someone else can point out something we've overlooked so far.

Thanks everyone so far for your time!